STM32G4x ADC DR always zero
I am using a STM32G413KB Nucleo Board, I am trying to test ADC with the code I write I give below,
When I debug the code interrupt is triggering contuniously but ADC value don't change even I change voltage at PA6 pin. Any suggestion?
#include "main.h"

/* Private defines -----------------------------------------------------------*/


/* Private function prototypes -----------------------------------------------*/
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void);

void RCC_Configuration(void);

static void MX_ADC2_Init(void);

uint32_t adcval1;

int main(void)

{

    RCC_Configuration();
    MX_GPIO_Init();
    MX_ADC2_Init();

    while (1) {
        
    }

}

void RCC_Configuration(void) 

{

    RCC->CR |= RCC_CR_HSEON;
    while (!(RCC->CR & RCC_CR_HSERDY));


    FLASH->ACR |= FLASH_ACR_LATENCY_4WS;


    RCC->PLLCFGR = 0;
    RCC->PLLCFGR |= RCC_PLLCFGR_PLLSRC_HSE;


    RCC->PLLCFGR |= (3 << RCC_PLLCFGR_PLLM_Pos) | (50 << RCC_PLLCFGR_PLLN_Pos) | (0 << RCC_PLLCFGR_PLLR_Pos);
    RCC->PLLCFGR |= RCC_PLLCFGR_PLLREN;


    RCC->CR |= RCC_CR_PLLON;
    while (!(RCC->CR & RCC_CR_PLLRDY));


    RCC->CFGR &= ~RCC_CFGR_HPRE;
    RCC->CFGR |= RCC_CFGR_HPRE_DIV1;


    RCC->CFGR &= ~RCC_CFGR_PPRE1;
    RCC->CFGR |= RCC_CFGR_PPRE1_DIV1;


    RCC->CFGR &= ~RCC_CFGR_PPRE2;
    RCC->CFGR |= RCC_CFGR_PPRE2_DIV1;


    RCC->CFGR &= ~RCC_CFGR_SW;
    RCC->CFGR |= RCC_CFGR_SW_PLL;
    while (!(RCC->CFGR & RCC_CFGR_SWS_PLL));
    SystemCoreClockUpdate();

}

static void MX_GPIO_Init(void)

{
   
    RCC->AHB2ENR |= RCC_AHB2ENR_GPIOAEN;

    GPIOA->MODER |= GPIO_MODER_MODE6;
    
}

static void MX_ADC2_Init(void) 

{

    RCC->AHB2ENR |= RCC_AHB2ENR_ADC12EN;
    RCC->CCIPR &= ~RCC_CCIPR_ADC12SEL;
    RCC->CCIPR |= RCC_CCIPR_ADC12SEL_0;

    ADC12_COMMON->CCR &= ~(ADC_CCR_PRESC | ADC_CCR_CKMODE);
    ADC12_COMMON->CCR |= (ADC_CCR_CKMODE_0 | ADC_CCR_CKMODE_1 );
    ADC12_COMMON->CCR |= ADC_CCR_PRESC_3;


    ADC2->CR &= ~ADC_CR_ADEN;
    ADC2->CR |= ADC_CR_ADVREGEN;
    for (volatile uint32_t delay = 0; delay < 10000; delay++);

    ADC2->CR &= ~ADC_CR_ADCALDIF;
    ADC2->CR |= ADC_CR_ADCAL;


    while (ADC2->CR & ADC_CR_ADCAL);


    ADC2->CFGR &= ~ADC_CFGR_RES;
    ADC2->CFGR |= ADC_CFGR_CONT;
    ADC2->SQR1 = (3 << ADC_SQR1_SQ1_Pos);


    ADC2->IER |= ADC_IER_EOCIE;
    NVIC_EnableIRQ(ADC1_2_IRQn);


    ADC2->CR |= ADC_CR_ADEN;
    while (!(ADC2->ISR & ADC_ISR_ADRDY));


    ADC2->CR |= ADC_CR_ADSTART;

    while (!(ADC2->ISR & ADC_ISR_EOC));

    adcval1 = ADC2->DR;

}

void ADC1_2_IRQHandler(void)

{

    if (ADC2->ISR & ADC_ISR_EOC)

    {

        adcval1 = ADC2->DR;

    }

}

With ADC2 calibration changes as I share below, I can measure the voltage with ADC but now I have a problem that ADC measure same thing at first value. Even I change voltage there is a same data at ADC2-DR.
static void MX_ADC2_Init(void) {

    ADC2->CR &= ~ADC_CR_DEEPPWD;
    ADC2->CR |= ADC_CR_ADVREGEN;
    for (volatile uint32_t delay = 0; delay < 10000; delay++);
    ADC2->CR &= ~ADC_CR_ADEN;
    ADC2->CR &= ~ADC_CR_ADCALDIF;
    ADC2->CR |= ADC_CR_ADCAL;
    while (ADC2->CR & ADC_CR_ADCAL);


    ADC12_COMMON->CCR &= ~(ADC_CCR_PRESC | ADC_CCR_CKMODE);
    ADC12_COMMON->CCR |= (ADC_CCR_CKMODE_0 | ADC_CCR_CKMODE_1 );
    ADC12_COMMON->CCR |= ADC_CCR_PRESC_3;


    ADC2->CFGR &= ~ADC_CFGR_RES;
    ADC2->CFGR |= ADC_CFGR_CONT;
    ADC2->SQR1 = (3 << ADC_SQR1_SQ1_Pos);


    ADC2->IER |= ADC_IER_EOCIE;
    NVIC_EnableIRQ(ADC1_2_IRQn);


    ADC2->CR |= ADC_CR_ADEN;
    while (!(ADC2->ISR & ADC_ISR_ADRDY));


    ADC2->CR |= ADC_CR_ADSTART;

    while (!(ADC2->ISR & ADC_ISR_EOC));

    adcval1 = ADC2->DR;
}


If you put a breakpoint on ADC IRQ, do you get a hit?

Yes, i get. @MrGerber

Where do you clear the interrupt flag when handling EOC interrupt?

At g series mcu, flag cleared by itself if I am not wrong.

Checked the manual (RM0440 Rev8), yes that's right. EOC IF is cleared by reading ADC_DR.
Have you checked that CN3 Pin 7 (A5) is actually connected to PA6 on the MCU? There seems to be a solder bridge configuration on that pin on the Nucleo board. CN3 Pin A5 can be connected to either PA6 or PA15.

You're not putting signal on CN3 Pin 6 - (A6), maybe? A6 is wired to PA7, not PA6

I take a look at design file of nucleo board. I see solder bridge as you mentioned there is a zero ohm soldered so PA15 and PA6 connected to each other but is it cause that kind of problem? I don't think so because with multimeter I can see voltage at PA6.

I am putting signal at PA6 (A5).

Read out and check/post content of all ADC and relevant RCC registers. You appear to have selected PLL-P output as ADC clock in RCC_CCIPR.ADC12SEL, but don't seem to have set PLLPEN in RCC_PLLCFGR, did I overlook something?

Yes you are right about I didn't set PLL-P and other PLL (I don't remember) because I don't need to change reset values of that registers. But I will try to set them maybe somehow that can be the problem.
